# Live Sass Compiler

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

I'm using live sass compiler, but when I clicked the watch sass button, it's always show "Working On It". Here's my code

[image: Html]

[image: Scss]

Comment: I think, i made a mistake in scss codes (root)

Comment: Solved, just change the **`--main-font: font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;`** in the root to **`--main-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;`**

Comment: why post images of code, can't you copy/paste the code, very hard to search in images

Comment: I'm sorry, at that moment I feel really confused. So I forget this web can copy and paste the code, I really sorry mate, but the problem already solved. Thanks for your attention btw